# Instantiating List<T> with generic type possible?

Tags: java, generics, objectinstantiation

A student that I am tutoring is taking a web development class that uses a Dietel book on Java, which contains this curious bit of code involving Generics:

```
class StackComposition <T>
{
    private List<T> stackList;

    public StackComposition()
    {
        stackList = new List<T>("stack")  // ERROR
    }

    // .... more code
}
```

It is apparent to me why this code doesn't work, and I am puzzled as to why the instructor recommends the student use this code as a starting point. Maybe I am just not understanding Generics and my Java skills are deficient, but I don't see how one could instantiate a generic collection with a generic type. I see the intent is to create a Stack by using a generic List collection and determining the type at runtime, but I don't see how this is possible using the above configuration. My first inclination was to tell the student to use the Generic `Stack<T>` object and forget writing this custom Stack class, but apparently that isn't the goal of the assignment.

I tried as a test using the `java.lang.reflect` package to work around this, but as far as I can tell this only works with non-generic containers, such as `Array`:

```
public StackComposition(Class<T> type)
{
    Object obj = Array.newInstance(type, 10);
}
```

Comment: How about `stackList = new ArrayList<T>()`?

Comment: `stackList = new List<T>("stack")` if you are referring to `java.util.List` its pretty obvious why that line wouldn't compile. cuz, List is an interface and you can't instantiate one.

Comment: on second tought, by seeing your declaration again. i think `List` is a custom type as `any List implementing sub-types` dont have  a `constructor` that take `String` as an argument

Comment: @PremGenError assuming you're right, then the problem is in `some.weird.package.List` class implementation, not in the presented code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  i don't see `java.util.List` import as well. lets wait till OP makes it clear .. :)

Comment: @PremGenError usually few people copy/paste the wall code including package imports. Still, I think it is `java.util.List` since OP wanted to initialize an array using reflection (which becomes in a weirder solution).

Comment: You guys are both correct. I did include `java.util.List`, and was attempting to instantiate an abstract class `List<T>`. (I keep forgetting that C# and Java are, in fact, different languages). It could just be an error on the author's part, or perhaps they defined their own custom List class (the most likely case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

You're trying to instantiate an interface with `new` keyword which is illegal. You should be instantiating an object of `ArrayList` (or a class which implements `List`) instead.

Second, you're not allowed to pass a `String` reference to the constructor.

So, here is what you should be using in your code:

```
stackList = new ArrayList<T>();
```

or `stackList = new ArrayList<T>(10);` if you want to give an initial size to your `stackList` (replace `10` with the size you want your list to be initialized with).

Comment: Thank You. I found earlier on in the book that the author was indeed using their own `List` class. But in their example code for the above, they used their own package. This should have been the clue for me

Answer (score 0):

From a purely instructional point of view, the exercise may have been meant to illustrate *composition* by *forwarding* certain methods to a contained instance of some more general type. Only the desired methods need be exposed, and the concrete type used internally can be changed as needed.

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MyStack<T> {

    private Deque<T> deque = new LinkedList<T>();

    public void push(T item){
        deque.push(item);
    }

    public T pop() {
        return deque.pop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStack<Integer> stack = new MyStack<>();
        stack.push(42); // OK
        stack.addFirst(0); // no such method
    }
}
```